# Running a batch script containing 'git bash' commands without launching 'git bash'

Tags: windows, bash, sh, git-bash

I had a batch script on Linux which ran some 'git bash' commands when I launched it from a terminal. Now my Linux laptop is broken and then I lost this script and I don't remember its contents. I have a Windows machine now and I'd like to reproduce the equivalent script.

What I have been able to do is this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add /c/Users/sdl96354/.ssh/id_ed25519_laustep
git add -A
git commit -m %1
git push
```

It does what I want but in order to run it I have to run 'git bash' first and then I have to type `sh thisfile.bat "commit message"`. I would like to just type `thisfile.bat "commit message"` from an ordinary terminal, what should I do?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Windows follows extensions to know how to deal with a file. A `bat` file will not be run against `bash`. Try setting the extension to `.sh` instead of `.bat`.

Comment: @eftshift0 You are correct. Thanks. But I still have to launch `git bash` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a batch script but a shell script. You shouldn't name its extension as bat. Preferably name it with sh.

The problem with your script is it uses `%1` as a parameter "placeholder" a.k.a a positional parameter. Change it to `"$1"`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would you know whether it is possible to stop the script if I forget the commit message (the `"$1"`)? I often forget it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You can test the argument if it has been specified and not empty. You can start with `[[ ${1-} ]] || exit 1`. You can convert that to a verbose `if` block with an error message. Just look up a few topics about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an WSL linux installed on your computer, search for windows subsystem for linunx... it's a simple terminal in linux on your windows machine, its easy to install and usefull.

Or you can decide make all of this in windows prompt language... that's another wat to do that....